# Windows 10 crackling sound

Tags: windows-10, audio, amd-ryzen, nvidia, clicking-sound

Somethimes I hear **crackling sound** on my pc. I usually happens **after back from sleep mode**. And I can hear it only when other sounds *(ex. music, games)*.

**After booting pc everything works fine** until sleep.
I tried:

1. Close all running apps.
2. Reinstall sound driver.
3. Use microsoft utility to fix this.

Also I read that it can be caused by background electrical noise, but I think that I have problems with windows, because it happens after reinstalling it.
My pc is dual boot. There are no problems on second os (elementary os).

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lt1x.jpg

Spec: Ryzen 3 1200, 16GB Ram, Nvidia Geforce GTX 1060 3GB

Comment: Quite possibly poorly shielded motherboard. (I have had  few with same problem)  Windows drivers get A LOT more effort than Linux.. it is quite possible that the windows driver is accessing things on the mobo the Linux driver is not.  Also.. when >I< have had this problem, they have been REALLY GOOD motherboards.. (brand wise anyways)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas But why it works until sleep?

Comment: Good question.. if I had an answer, then I would have posted an ANSWER .. not a comment. ;^)  Windows has much better power management.. just like my comment on the drivers.. the answer might be the same.  I love Linux.. but it does some things better.. but windows seems to have better hardware support.  Perhaps windows is trying the disable/enable something Linux just leaves alone?? We are both guessing at solutions.. but might steer you toward your own solution.

Comment: Is it on-board sound? Are you using motherboard's sound drivers? If so what if you uninstall them and use default Windows 10 drivers? Does it happen randomly anywhere in audio being played or at specific points like start/end or end of looped piece of audio etc? Use Audacity (Windows) or any such free app and record the sound from Stereo-Mix input device.  Do you see any DC offset generated in the audio waveform?

Comment: @patkim I use MSI Realtek Audio Console. I can happen any time after pc back from sleep in any player (aimp, spotify) or games (csgo, osu). I also tried to record screen with Geforce experience and sound was without any issues. I'll try to uninstall drive now and write back

Comment: If you disconnect external speakers and plugin your earphones/headphones, do you hear it in headphones as well?

Comment: @patkim i use speakers in back input, and headphones in front

Comment: I was coming to - if the crackling is consistent in external speakers as well as headphones to possibly isolate the issue. Hence suggested to disconnect speakers and check if headphones also give same crackling. Just thinking if  it is originating in the sound card processing or thereafter in any other circuitry.